# How to fix deprecated createQuery method for an Update query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am upgrading the legacy code to Hibernate 6. I am getting deprecation warning for createQuery method for Update query. How do I fix this code? Google search just gives examples of old API only.

```
public static int setLastIpTimeStamp(Timestamp ipLastTimeStamp)
        {
            int rowsaffected = -1;
            try (Session session = SessionFactoryManager.getSessionFactory().openSession())
            {
                Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE HistoryDataProcessorSettingsEntity row SET row.ipLastTimeStamp=:ipLastTimeStamp WHERE row.id=:id ")
                            .setParameter("id", 1)
                            .setParameter("ipLastTimeStamp", ipLastTimeStamp.toInstant());
                    rowsaffected = query.executeUpdate();
                    tx.commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    tx.rollback();
                    if (Logger.isErrorEnabled())
                        Logger.error(e);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (Logger.isErrorEnabled())
                    Logger.error(e);
            }
            return rowsaffected;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the latest [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)) , you should use [`createMutationQuery()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-MutationQuery) instead as you are doing update only :

```java
MutationQuery query = session.createMutationQuery("UPDATE HistoryDataProcessorSettingsEntity row SET row.ipLastTimeStamp=:ipLastTimeStamp WHERE row.id=:id ")
                            .setParameter("id", 1)
                            .setParameter("ipLastTimeStamp", ipLastTimeStamp.toInstant());
```